# Add Page Layouts to a wsp file SharePoint 2013

Tags: page-layout, solution-package

I'm trying to add some custom page layouts to an existent wsp solution for SharePoint 2013, I have edited the element.xml and the features.xml.
The file is uploaded and I can see it with SharePoint designer but it is not recognized as a pagelayout.

I tried a sample snippet from the 2010 version but it doesn't work for the 2013, bellow is the code that I used.

```
<Module Name="_catalogsmasterpageAteaRapidpagelayouts_" Url="_catalogs/masterpage" RootWebOnly="FALSE" Path="Files\_catalogs\masterpage">           
    <File Path="masterpage\teste.aspx" Url="teste.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
      <Property Name="Title" Value="My Custom Page Layout" />
      <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;" />
      <Property Name="PublishingPreviewImage" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/CustomPageLayout.png, ~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/$Resources:core,Culture;/Preview Images/CustomPageLayout.png" />
      <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType" Value=";#$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_articlepage_name;;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D;#"/>
    </File>
</Module>
```

Building the wsp again with the visual studio is not an option.

Anyone have the snippet code to add the page layout to the 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writting this code in your Elements.xml

```
<Module Name="Layout" Url="_catalogs/masterpage">
  <File Path="Layout\teste.aspx" Url="teste.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
    <Property Name="Title" Value="Layout Intranet Home"></Property>
    <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType" Value=";#$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_articlepage_name;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39002211F99918BD4D80B8E1DEF7585F0F9A;#" ></Property>
    <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;"></Property>
  </File>
</Module>
```

This code works for me. Look at this piece of your code `#$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_articlepage_name;;` You have double ;;